# EF Core 2 + Relacionamentos entre tabelas

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Olá, estou iniciando um projeto, e comecei utilizando pela primeira vez o novo EF Core, por questão de performasse, porem ainda tem algumas coisas que não encontrei na internet que gostaria de fazer.

No meu projeto eu tenho 3 classes

Usuarios - Base

UsuarioRole - Regras de usuarios

UsuarioConta - Informações da conta do usuario

Processos - Processos do sistema

Usuario + roles = 1 usuario pode ter varias roles, e 1 role pode ser de varios usuario; Relacionamento de N : N

Usuario + Conta = 1 usuario pode ter 1 conta, e 1 conta pode ser de 1 usuario; Relacionamento de 1 : 1

Usuario + Processo = 1 usuario pode ter varios processos, e 1 processo pode ser de 1 usuario; Relacionamento de N : 1

Estou utilizando a interface IEntityTypeConfiguration, para fazer as configurações separadas.

Gostaria de saber, como eu faço esses relacionamentos utilizando o FluentApi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei  um site aonde detalha todos os tipos de relacionamentos

Um P/ um: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration

Um P/ muitos: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration

muitos P/ muitos: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Apenas segue os passos de cada um e aplique em sua aplicação...